# How do I use DateTime in PHP to get the next occurrence of a specific time of day, either today if not past, or tomorrow if past?

Tags: php, datetime

How can I use DateTime in PHP to get the next occurrence of a specific time of day, such at 5PM, relative to the current time - either 5PM today if the current time is < 5PM, or 5PM tomorrow if the current time today >= 5PM.

The failing code I'm using is:

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$today = new DateTime('next 5PM');
echo $today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

These work:

```
$today = new DateTime('5PM');
$today = new DateTime('today 5PM');
$today = new DateTime('tomorrow 5PM');
$today = new DateTime('yesterday 5PM');
```

But I wanted to using one statement get the DateTime for 5PM today if the current time is < 5PM, or the DateTime for 5PM tomorrow, if the current time now is >= 5PM.

Can this simply be done in one statement with DateTime? If so, does it depend on PHP version?

I get Fatal Errors trying:

```
$today = new DateTime('next 5PM');
```

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you cannot find the solution in PHP library, just program it.

Hint:

1. Take DateTime object from the current time - $now.
2. Get $now->format('H') and convert it to integer
3. Compare the value to 17 and depending on result, use 'today 5PM' or 'tomorrow 5PM'

If you do everything right, you need 3-7 lines of code depending on your coding style

Answer (score 0):

You can compare current hour with 5PM like below

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

if (date('H') < 17) {
   $next = new DateTime('yesterday 5PM');
}
else{
    $next = new DateTime('tomorrow 5PM');
}


echo $next->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```